# Failed to Reexport component's in directory.js

Tags: reactjs, export, filepath

I have tried to follow the suggestion of making all exports named and of course, use a file (ideally index.js) as a reference to various pages. But the console keeps saying

```
./src/directory.js
"export 'default' (reexported as 'rAbout') was not found in './Pages/Resume/rAbout/rAbout'
```

Which is obviously in the right location so I don't know what the problem is. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/JonthueM/reaact_Jonthue_Website).

File in directory.js
export { default as rAbout } from './Pages/Resume/rAbout/rAbout';

[Clip of path as shown in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1x4S.png)

Answer (score 0):

I removed *default as*  from the export and it worked liked magic. Maybe there was a conflict.